# How to get user list with password in azure api management service with REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have created a resource in Azure API Management Service, Also by using a developer console portal template, the user can sign in and sign up and test listed API from there.

By using Management API I am getting the list of users who signed up through the developer portal.
[image]

Using management API as below,

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/users?api-version=2019-12-01
```

I am getting the user list without a password as below using Management API,

```
    {
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/1xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/groupName/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/serviceName/users/5xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users",
            "name": "5xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "properties": {
                "firstName": "string",
                "lastName": "string",
                "email": "testuser@yahoo.com",
                "state": "active",
                "registrationDate": "2020-09-25T17:15:02.587Z",
                "note": null,
                "identities": [
                    {
                        "provider": "Basic",
                        "id": "testuser@yahoo.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "count": 1
}
```

I referred below documents,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/user/listbyservice

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service/users

Now, I want a password with this response object with users' data. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Also please check the below screen dump,

[image]

Above users signup using the developer portal template, If I can authenticate APIs using their user's credentials, Or in another way, I would say that only signed up can use API that I have published on API management service.

Thank a lot.

Comment: Proper password management is for applications *not* to store a users plaintext password. It's simply not needed. Instead, passwords are one way hashed and salted. Then when a user needs to log in, the password they provided is hashed, and compared to the stored hashed value.

Comment: @mason Thanks for the replay. Is there any other way available that I can verify the developer portal signed up external users with their credentials (username and password)?

Comment: Have them sign in.

Comment: @mason I want to get users who signed up from my portal, In the user tab of the portal I can see a list of users but I want users password using API or any other way to get those users' details?

Comment: As we already explained, you are not able to retrieve user passwords, because that would be a huge security violation. You need to change your approach. If you need single sign on across multiple apps, then look into Azure Active Directory or some other form of user management.

Comment: @mason Is there any way available that I can secure uploaded API with those users who signed up through the developer console portal?

Comment: Didn't I already suggest Azure Active Directory? Are you saying you already looked into it?

Comment: @mason I have attached another screen dump in question, please have a look into it. That user tab shows the user list who signed in through the developer console template (Contoso). I want to authenticate my API using these users, that's the point. Please help for the same.

Comment: Your screenshot does not change the fact that Microsoft does not provide a mechanism for obtaining a user's password. If you want to authenticate against a Microsoft account or Azure Active Directory, there are methods of doing that. You need to go research how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would **expect** that the API does not provide the password. And even if it did, it would almost certainly only be a hash. Why would you want to get a users password?? That would be a big security issue.

Comment: Thank you for replay. I want to store registered user's credentials and user information in the database, so these registered users can use my other application using the same credentials. Can you please let me know how I can get user information including password in any form Hash or Plain? Or is there any functionality available that we can get user's information on the time of sign-up through the developer portal?

Comment: I don't see any API for this and I very doubt this is available.

Comment: Okay, so is there any functionality or API available, if users pass their username and password then it will return that users are valid or not?

Comment: Don't know - but also dont think so